# Getting text from various <td> within a <table>

Tags: html, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to get a value (the text) of the first `<td>` tag of each `<tr>` but I was not successful

In the example below, what I would be trying to achieve would be: `juicy vic`

How can I get this value using the `cheerio` module, what would be the most certain way to get these values ​​from the `<td>` tags?

```
<table class="partners">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Nome do Summoner</th>
         <th>Posição</th>
         <th>Tier</th>
         <th>Campeão Recente</th>
         <th>Chances</th>
         <th>KDA</th>
         <th>Nota</th>
         <th>Registrado</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="partners">
      <tr class="group" id="partner-86729" phx-click="delete" phx-target="1" data-phx-component="1">
         <td>
            <a id="partner-86729-name" href="https://br.op.gg/summoner/userName=juicy vic ?utm_source=duo.lol&amp;utm_medium=partner-list&amp;utm_campaign=permanent" target="_blank" phx-hook="StopPropagation" class="partner__profile partner__link">
            <img src="//opgg-static.akamaized.net/images/profile_icons/profileIcon3542.jpg?image=q_auto:best&amp;v=1518361200">
            juicy vic 
            </a>
         </td>
         <td id="partner-86729-edit-position" phx-hook="PartnerEditHook">
            <span class="position-container">
               <svg class="position-icon support" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M13.991 8.327l2.248-2.036H24c-2.553 2.327-4.69 2.86-5.44 2.836h-1.45l2.03 2.91-3.553 1.527-1.596-5.237zM14.644 19.745L12.758 9.127l-.798.946V22l2.684-2.255zM10.009 8.327L7.76 6.291H0c2.553 2.327 4.69 2.86 5.44 2.836h1.45l-2.03 2.91 3.553 1.527 1.596-5.237zM9.277 19.745l1.886-10.618.797.946V22l-2.683-2.255zM9.048 2L8.25 3.382 11.876 7.6l3.627-4.218L14.56 2H9.048z"></path>
               </svg>
               <span class="position-container__tooltip">
               Suporte
               </span>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div class="flex-container">
               <img src="/images/tiers/unranked-73687a6509dfb61e1f84b01150173ed0.png?vsn=d" class="partner__tier">
               Unranked
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div class="partner__champions">
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>
            0승
            0패
            <span class="dimmed">
            (<span class="red">0%</span>)
            </span>
         </td>
         <td>
            3.1<span class="separator">/</span>5.5<span class="separator">/</span>21.4
            <span class="dimmed">
            (<span class="green">4.45</span>)
            </span>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div id="partner-86729-edit-note" phx-hook="PartnerEditHook" class="partner__note">
               alguem quer jogar normal game
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="partner__inserted" title="2021-05-19 12:33:38">
            3 minutos atrás
            <div class="opacity-25 group-hover:opacity-100 hover:text-red-600 transition-opacity" phx-click="report" phx-target="1">
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-4 w-4 inline-block" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 9v2m0 4h.01m-6.938 4h13.856c1.54 0 2.502-1.667 1.732-3L13.732 4c-.77-1.333-2.694-1.333-3.464 0L3.34 16c-.77 1.333.192 3 1.732 3z"></path>
               </svg>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried the code below but was unsuccessful:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
$('body > #partners > tbody > tr > td').toArray().map(item => {
    console.log($(item).text());
});
```

Comment: Hi Maicon, please change your code as $('body > tbody#partners > tr > td') and try again.

Answer (score 0):

That would just be:

```
$('td:nth-of-type(1)').get().map(td => $(td),text())
```